# trying to send data to html page to view from controller in spring boot but i am only reciving my html page name

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

```
 @RequestMapping("/")

    public String viewHomePage(Model model ){
        model.addAttribute("users",userRegisService.getUser());
        return"listUser";}
```

> User Name
>                 User password
>                  User Email
>                 User place of birth

get as response
**listUser**

Comment: Did you use `@Controller` or `@RestController` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.